# How can I dynamically adjust contentInset in scrollViewDidZoom? I initially set contentInset of UIImageView in UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm on a project that makes an custom `'Move and Scale' Controller` of `UIImagePickerController`. (controller when appear if `imagePickerController.allowsEditing=YES`)

I want to `crop an UIImage` in the crop rectangular like the picture below.

[image: screenshot 1]

And I made some code to set `contentInset`.

```
    self.selectedImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    CGRect cropRect = [SKPhotoCropFrameView getCropRectFromOrientation:self.photoCropOrientation];
    CGRect aspectFitRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.selectedImageView.image.size, self.selectedImageView.frame);
    CGFloat difference = fabsf(cropRect.size.height - aspectFitRect.size.height);
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(difference/2, 0, difference/2 + 20, 0);   // 20 is status bar height
```

and here is the result.

[image: screenshot 2]

Black region is contentInset area.

However, if I pinch this scrollView to zoom in, something happen.

[image: screenshot 3]

I think I have to do something on

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

to adjust contentInset dynamically. How can I do this? Please give me some help :)

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but your approach is different from apple's and that's the problem. They do not allow scrolling down when the image is fully zoomed out, you can't just zoom in an upper part of an image when using pinch gesture. You'll either need to change your approach to the one apple uses and restrict the area of zoom or use some UI elements to perform zoom programmatically, that way you'll have a complete control over the area you're zooming.

Comment: @Eugene Thank you for your comment. I think my approach is exactly the same way with Apple's. I mimic the default UIImagePickerController. I just want to implement default UIImagePickerController 'Move and Scale' Controller. Would you explain why this is different from Apple's more sophisticately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hoped someone answered this question, I'm sad because it's not.

But thank God, I solved this.

in

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

adjust contentInset dynamically using zoomScale. I just implement only `Lanscape mode` for testing, but `Portrait mode` is exactly the same way.

```
// adjust contentInset
CGFloat increasingZoomScale = (scrollView.zoomScale == 1) ? 0 : (-1 * (1 - scrollView.zoomScale));

CGRect cropRect = [SKPhotoCropFrameView getCropRectFromOrientation:self.photoCropOrientation];
CGRect aspectFitRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.selectedImageView.image.size, self.selectedImageView.frame);
CGFloat difference = fabsf(cropRect.size.height - aspectFitRect.size.height);

// implement at `Landscape` mode first
if (self.photoCropOrientation == SKPhotoCropOrientationPortrait) {

}else{
    // get scaledFrameHeight because it's `Landscape` crop mode
    CGFloat increasingFrameHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height * increasingZoomScale;
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(difference/2 - increasingFrameHeight/2, 0, difference/2 - increasingFrameHeight/2, 0);
}
```

And bam. here is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot 4]